# Have you used any object database in a web application? Could you share your experiences?

Tags: .net, database, object-oriented-database

We are looking to rewrite a small web-application and would like to try out an object (not document) database like db4O or Eloquera. We have some experience with object databases, but these however have been for small client/server applications.

Could you share your experiencess on:

- How well do these databases scale? We are currently using SQL Server and we have 50-60 tables. 2 tables have more than 1 million rows each (8-10 columns), but the others have less than 25 K rows. (MDF file ~ 890 MB)
- As some of theser are hosted in process, how do you make them work in web farm/garden scenarios?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [Seaside on Gemstone](http://seaside.gemstone.com/). Just start the tutorial "Web development with Seaside". With this amount of data the free version (up to 2G of ram and 2 cores) should be fine. It makes sense to use an OO model instead of a relational one, and do much more normalization than you'd do with SQL server.

For the bulk import you probably want to write some topaz scripts.